# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘ajax’ of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am using requirejs and in my index I have

and In main.js I have

```
require(["jquery","employeeManager","employeeData"], function ($,employeeManger,employeeData) {
alert("main.js funtion");
var main= employeeManger.loadStudentData();

return main;

})

and in employeemanger
loadStudentData : function(){

$.ajax({
//url:"http://localhost:63342/NewnodeJsProject/public/data/studentData.json",
url:"http://localhost:63342/NewnodeJsProject/public/data/studentData.json",
method:'get',
success:this.handlerData

})
}
```

i am loading dependencies properly.. then why i am getting the uncaught error: cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

Comment: Why do you expect `$` to exist there?

Comment: define(["jquery-1.9.0.min","handlebars"],function ($,handlebars) {


        var Employee_METHOD ={handlerData:function(resJSON){var templateSource   = $("#employee-template").html(),
  template = handlebars.compile(templateSource),
         studentHTML = template(resJSON);
           $('#mydiv').html(studentHTML);
                console.log($("#employee-template"))
            },
            loadStudentData : function(){
$.ajax({
url:"http://localhost:63342/NewnodeJsProject/public/data/studentData.json",method:'get',
      success:this.handlerData

                })
            }
        };

Comment: this is my original code . where i am using requirejs and jqury

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `require` doesn't create globals. You can't use a variable declared in one module in a different one.

You must either:

- pass `$` to `loadStudentData` (as an argument) when you call it *or*
- `require` jQuery inside employeeManager